# Magento Remove .html from the product page urls and category page urls

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

My urls are starting to get a bit lengthy and I would like to remove the .html extension from the end of the urls to make them a bit shorter.  I cannot find the setting to remove or modify this option.  Please help me find the code or setting to make this change.  I am using Magento 1.9.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's really easy to do.  I'm not sure how Magento handles redirects after you modify the url extensions but you may want to consider that before changing urls on a live site, it may affect indexed urls.  `System > Config > Catalog > Catalog > Search Engine Optimization`.  There, you can modify product url and category url suffixes.  When you're done, make sure to go to `System > Index Management` and reindex all the data.  Then it's good practice to clear the cache as well (`System > Cache Management`).

Comment: I was looking for the SEO tab... It's actually labeled, "Search Engine Optimization".

Comment: I've updated my answer.  Thanks for letting me know.